# How can I use the MySQL FIELD() function within a SelectQuery object in Views?

Tags: 7, views, database

I want to use the MySQL `FIELD()` function to alter a query so that it orders a particular field on a particular order of keys.

The keys for this 'select' field are: active, under_contract, sold

I want to sort the View so that all of my results are sorted *first* by `node.created DESC` (this is simple, of course) and then push all `sold` nodes to the very bottom of the result.

I tried doing this first in hook_views_post_execute():

```
function mymodule_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view') {
    usort($view->result, function($a, $b) {
      return ($a->field_field_status[0]['raw']['value'] == 'sold') ? 1 : -1;
    });
  }
}
```

but quickly discovered that, since my view only shows 25 results per page, this only pushes `sold` nodes to the bottom of each page.

Next, I tried to use `hook_views_query_alter()` to add the awesome MySQL `FIELD()` function that I just discovered – which works to achieve my goal perfectly in MySQL - but can't be added (at least as I'm discovering) to a SelectQuery object, which Views uses to run the query:

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view') {
    $query->orderby[0] = array(
      'field' => " FIELD(field_data_field_status.field_status_value, 'sold') ",
      'direction' => 'DESC',
  );
  }
}
```

How can I add a `FIELD()` orderby function to this query? Is there another method to push a particular filter value to the bottom of the result queue?

Comment: Thats not how you add an orderby to a SelectQuery built with db_select(). you use the `orderBy()` function I believe. See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_select/7#comment-13489

Install the Devel module and dpm($query); in your hook_views_query_alter(), which should be MYMODULE_views_query_alter() ....

Comment: `$query->orderby` consists of arrays of `[field],[direction]`. See: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AorderBy/7. When Views formalizes the `$query` array it runs the `->orderBy()` method. Since `$query` in `hook_views_query_alter()` is simply an array and not yet an instantiation of a SelectQuery object, throwing ->orderBy() at it throws a fatal error, `Call to undefined method`.

Comment: For further explanation, see http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7. At this stage, we don't treat this as a true SelectQuery object but an array that describes the query and contains all of the arguments that these methods need (such as `orderBy($field, $direction)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working! I couldn't find any way to get the `orderBy` working in `hook_views_query_alter()`, so I tried to do this in the raw `hook_query_alter()`. In my particular situation, I couldn't get any result when I filtered against the table that Views had already joined with (I can't explain why) and so I added my own join. Voila, it works.

```
function mymodule_query_alter($query) {
  if ($query->hasTag('my_view_id')) {
    // Remove the current sort order. 
    $order =& $query->getOrderBy();
    $order = array();

    // Join with the table that we need, giving it a custom alias.
    $query->join('field_data_field_listing_status', 'custom_status', 'custom_status.entity_id = node.nid');

    // Add our cool FIELD() function to push all 'sold' nodes to the very back of the list.
    $query->orderBy("FIELD(custom_status.field_listing_status_value, 'sold')", 'ASC');

    // Add any other ordering that we need...
    $query->orderBy('node_created', 'DESC');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer (thanks). I found a way to do it within the views API.

"5,2,1,4" is just a random order of ids, so you can replace this by whatever field and keys you wish.

```
function HOOK_views_post_build ($view) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view' && $view->current_display == 'my_display') {
      $view->build_info['query']->orderBy("FIELD(id,5,2,1,4)", 'ASC');
    }
  }
}
```