# Instr() function on drupal

Tags: database

I need a funtionality for search tags from a textarea (drupal form), I make it from sql, then, mysql have this function:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html
I believe that oracle/pql does have same function.

```
select * from cms_tags ct 
 where instr('Americana Abstract Art Art Antique Jewelry Antique Jewelry Jewelry', ct.name);
```

How can I use that query in drupal way? using db_select() or something else.

Answer (score 3):

A plain `db_query()` might be easier for this particular query, but if you want to use `db_select()` you can make use of the [`SelectQuery::where()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Awhere/7) method:

```
$string = 'Americana Abstract Art Art Antique Jewelry Antique Jewelry Jewelry';

$query = db_select('cms_tags', 'ct')
  ->fields('ct')
  ->where('INSTR(:string, ct.name)', array(':string' => $string));
```

Comment: Clive: Does this actually work for you? I can't get MySQL functions to work within a SelectQuery object, at least those that aren't more widely available.

Comment: @CharlieS Yep seems to work fine, I just tried `$string = 'video'; $query = db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n')->where('INSTR(:string, n.type)', array(':string' => $string));` and it returned exactly what was expected. `where()` _should_ just pass through the string you give it after replacing the arguments, so theoretically if the function exists in MySQL there shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @Clive you deserve a gold star, sir. Your confidence caused me to revisit an issue I had at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52446/how-can-i-use-the-mysql-field-function-within-a-selectquery-object-in-views and realize I could really force my MySQL FIELD() function through. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Just run it through [db_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7).

Try this:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {cms_tags} ct WHERE INSTR('Americana Abstract Art Art Antique Jewelry Antique Jewelry Jewelry', ct.name);")->fetchAll());
print_r($result);
```

Comment: All seems good, this is the output: http://pastebin.com/K9U9vVSm

Comment: Hey Charlie!, that works :), all is OK, thanks bro!! :)